# Combinations of two lists in Python while preserving "column" order

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I have an original list in Python that look like this:

```
list = [a, 1, b, 2, c, 3]
```

I've split it into two lists as follows:

```
list_1 = [a, b, c]
list_2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

What I want to find is a final list of lists that gives me all the possible combinations of `list_1` and `list_2` **without** changing any letter or number from their current "column". So the output should look like that:

Desired output:

```
final_list =[[a, b, c],
             [a, 2, c],
             [a, b, 3],
             [a, 2, 3],
             [1, b, c],
             [1, 2, c],
             [1, b, 3],
             [1, 2, 3]]
```

Any ideas how I might be able to achive this?

Comment: what is the logic you are following to create the desired output?

Comment: Each "column" represents a single variable. Let's say the variable of the first "column" can have the value of either `a` or `1`. The variable of the second column can have the value of either 'b' or '2', etc. What I want is to have all the possible combinations of those variables (i.e. "columns") given that on the output, the first column can only have `a` or `1`; the second `b` or `2` etc. What cannot happen if for letter `c` or number `3` to appear in the first "column" because that would mean the variable represented in the first "column" would have a value belonging to another variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a brute-force recursive approach:

```
def get_combinations(curr_list, list1, list2, index, overall_list):
    if index == len(list1) or index == len(list2):
        overall_list.append(curr_list[:])
        return

    curr_list[index] = list1[index]
    get_combinations(curr_list, list1, list2, index+1, overall_list)
    curr_list[index] = list2[index]
    get_combinations(curr_list, list1, list2, index+1, overall_list)


list1 = list(input().strip().split())
list2 = list(input().strip().split())
overall_list = []
curr_list = [None] * min(len(list1), len(list2))
get_combinations(curr_list, list1, list2, 0, overall_list)
for l in overall_list:
    print(*l)
```

Input:

```
a b c
1 2 3
```

Output:

```
a b c
a b 3
a 2 c
a 2 3
1 b c
1 b 3
1 2 c
1 2 3
```

Comment: This works very well for printing out the results. But how could I modify it to give me a list of lists with all the solutions instead of printing it on the screen? I tried creating a list before the function and appending to it instead of doing `print(curr_list)`, but that did not work. The values get replaced by the final ones as the loops go on

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly. Hopefully one day I can fully understand the logic to apply it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier to look at your problem this way:

`list = [a, 1, b, 2, c, 3]`

Make three lists, one for the values the first number can take, one for the second and one for the third:

```
first = [a,1]
second = [b,2]
third = [c,3]
```

To generate every combination, you can combine three for loops that iterate over the elements of your three lists. Which list is used in which for loop changes the order in which the combinations are generated. I made my example match your output:

```
for f in first:
    for t in third:
        for s in second:
            //Here you have a [f,s,t] combination
```

Comment: That's probably a better way to look at it. The problem is that I can have any number of variables ("columns"), so how could I know the number of for loops i'd need in advance to loop through all of them?

Comment: Hmm, I can see a solution to that, but it's a bit more involved. I would make a recursive method that takes a list of "columns" and a "prefix" of values already chosen as argument. I can try to write it down for you if the other is not entirely satisfactory, although I am not familiar with Python syntax :P